# how to mute the .swf video while playing?

Tags: xhtml

Actually i tried the below HTML command for mute the flash video.

```
enter code here
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html;  charset=ISO-8859-1">
<TITLE>Sound OFF</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"       codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="500" HEIGHT="200" id="header123" ALIGN="">
<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="file:///opt/python/data/107.swf?playSound=var_stop"> 
<PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
<PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#FFFFFF> 
<EMBED src="file:///opt/python/data/107.swf?playSound=var_stop" quality=high bgcolor=#FFFFFF WIDTH="500" HEIGHT="200" NAME="header123" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</EMBED>
</OBJECT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, you cant mute a Flash Video over HTML, unless the developer implemented a parameter for it inside of the Flash.

playSound=var_stop could work, if this parameter is handled inside of the Flash - but probably it's not.

You will have to change the flash so that it can handle a parameter for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tt=[];
tt=document.getElementsByTagName('object');

for (i in tt) {
       try {
           typeof tt[i] == 'function' && tt[i].mute();
        } catch (err) {
        }
    }
```

it stop all object sound on current page . It work for me